# How to ignore the specific word in a string using python regular expression?

Tags: python

In the below code block I want to ignore  '@' and "everything" using python regular expression to get the output "match upto"
Can me anyone help me?

```
import re
mytext = "@ match everything upto"
myex = re.compile(r"") # Here I want to put regular expression
matches = re.findall(myex, mytext)
print (matches)
for i in matches:
     print(i)
     print (len(matches))
```

Comment: Why regex, why not just `str.replace`?

Comment: It's not clear what's your purpose... anyway you can start reading basic regex tutorials: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 2):

This is what you were looking for `re.sub`

```
import re
mytext = "@ match everything upto"
myex = re.compile(r"(@|everything)")
final_str = re.sub(myex, '',mytext)
print(final_str)
```

output:

```
 match  upto
```

Explanations:

```
re.compile(r"(@|everything)")
```

The above `re` just means `@` or `everything`. And `re.sub()` takes three arguments `re.sub(pattern,replacement_string,string_to_be_searched)`

So in your case : `re.sub(myex, '',mytext)` where replacement string is an empty string `''`

Comment: Thank your Vishnu Please suggest me if any other way that I can do the same

Comment: I have posted a new answer. Select one as correct answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve  the same using `list comprehensions`

```
mytext = "@ match everything upto"
r_items=['@','everything']

mytext = [x for x in mytext.split() if x not in r_items]


print(' '.join(mytext))
```

output:

```
match upto
```

Comment: Suppose if I have a paragraph if I want to get the list of every second word of the every line in that paragraph, How can I do that using a regular expression?